# Horn clause for the following formula

Tags: algorithms, logical-validity

Let be

$$F=A\land (\neg A\lor B)\land(A\lor \neg C)\land(\neg A\lor\neg B\lor D)\land(\neg A\lor\neg B\lor\neg C)$$

a formula. Is $F$ satisfiable?

Well, firstly, I've put $F$ into another form:

$$F\equiv (1\to A)\land(A\to B)\land(C\to A)\land(A\land B\to D)\land(A\land B\land C\to 0).$$

Then, I've started with HORNSAT:

- Mark $A$, because of $1\to A$.
- Mark $B$, because of $A\to B$.
- Mark $D$, because of $A\land B\to D$.

How can I go on?

Comment: Do $(A\wedge B \rightarrow \neg C)$ for the last clause instead.

Comment: One approach that always works is to enumerate all possible assignments.  For this particular formula, there are only $2^4=16$ of them, so it's not that hard: start drawing a truth table, and you'll be done before you know it.  Are you really asking us to do that for you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to prove that $F$ is *valid* and not that it is *satisfiable*?

By "$F$ is valid" we mean that $F$ holds true under all truth assignments of its propositions. Just by looking at the 1st conjunct, it seems that if $A$ is false, already $F$ does not hold true.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry.